# Laravel Authentication - How does it work?

Tags: php, laravel

Genuinely curious (the docs didn't give any advanced details) on how Laravel's authentication works.

Curious because I need it to work on the front end of my app, right now I call

```
Auth::login($User, true)
```

But when I go to a separate page and do this

```
$User = Auth::user();
return response($User);
```

It returns null. Any idea why? I'm definitely just using the Auth system wrong

Comment: Any route that uses Auth() must be encapsulated in the web middleware.

Comment: This link may help you to create your auth https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-laravel-app-and-adding-authentication/

Comment: I'd like it to just be using the Auth command if possible. I don't know how to word what I need best though. I just want the fact that the user is authenticated to show between different requests to the controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to be setting the `auth` middleware for all the routes you need protected. See:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#protecting-routes

`Auth::login($User, true)` will work for the single request but if you're not storing the information in a session then it will be lost on subsequent requests.

Also make sure `AuthenticateSession` middleware is not commented out in the http kernel.

https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/AuthenticateSession.html

Comment: How do I store the info in the session?

Comment: I need to use the controller to log them in, the front end is a different application

Comment: Thats what the `auth` middleware does for you, it'll handle all the session storing automatically

Comment: How do I add the frontend website as a protected URL? The Laravel app is at /api and the base website is /, so how can I add that URL to the Laravel auth?

Comment: You'll typically set the auth middleware on route groups. For example, in `routes/web.php` add `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], function() { ... your route definitions ... });`

Comment: What will this achieve? I don't care about routes being not protected by auth, I just want the auth session saved between my front end and my backend, so when I log a user in on the backend it'll show them as logged in if I go Auth::user() in a different request

Comment: The Auth middleware is something that's used to reject a request if the user is not authenticated

Comment: @ZachHandley - `I don't care about routes being not protected by auth` - then why are you using authentication?

Comment: Because I need to access the logged in user?